# C# my class returns nothing from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, return, datareader

This is my class.

I have a method called `retrievecinemainfo` which connects with my other class called `Bioscoopinfo`. This method (`retrievecinemainfo`) is declared at my main form.

The problem is that when I want to retrieve the data from the database, it doesn't return it into the textboxes, it does collect the right data because I have seen it in the debugger. But when it passes my class constructor called `bioscoopinfo`, the values are empty all of a sudden and it doesn't return anything.

Can anyone please help?

```
class sqlconnectie
{
    public Bioscoopinfo retrievecinemainfo (string Locatie, string Bioscoop,  string Tijd)
    {
        Bioscoopinfo biosinfo = null;
        SqlDataReader myreader;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (myreader.Read())
            {
                 Locatie = myreader.GetString(1);
                 Bioscoop = myreader.GetString(2);
                 Tijd = myreader.GetString(3);

                 biosinfo = new Bioscoopinfo(Locatie, Bioscoop, Tijd);

                 string strpath = Application.StartupPath;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return biosinfo;
    }
}
```

and this here is my class where the values eventually return nothing:

```
class Bioscoopinfo
{
    public string locatie { get; set; }
    public string bioscoop { get; set; }
    public string tijd { get; set; }

    public Bioscoopinfo(string locatie, string bioscoop, string tijd)
    {
        this.locatie = "place";
        this.bioscoop = "cinema";
        this.tijd = "19:00";
    }
}
```

and this here is the code where my code will actually get used

```
connectie = new sqlconnectie();
connectie.stringcommand("SELECT * FROM Bios where Locatie = '" + comboBox1.Text + "' ");

string bioscoop = tbbioscoop.Text;
string locatie = tblocatie.Text;
string tijd = tbtijd.Text;

connectie.retrievecinemainfo(bioscoop, locatie, tijd);
```

Comment: Is it perhaps because you're not using the values in `Bioscoopinfo`'s constructor, and instead using hard-coded values of "place", "cinema", and "19:00"?

Comment: @john what you you suggest? because this.locatie=locatie; doesnt work

Comment: It should. What do you find if you debug through the constructor if you use it with `this.locatie = locatie`?

Comment: @john it does give the values from the database, however when i get to the code in the windows forms (connectie.retrevecinemainfo(bioscoop,locatie,tijd);                                it returns titel = "", beschrijving = null.

Comment: You're not assigning the returned object to anything, and you can't change the reference of an object (e.g. bioscoop) by passing it to a method, unless you use the `ref` or `out` keyword on the method definition and method call. (* You can change the values within the passed object if you pass a class or something)

Comment: @john i am sorry for troubling you, but i really dont know how i should change that!

Comment: Well, you could assign the object that your method returns to something and use that.

Comment: @john i can do that with a stringbuilder right?

Comment: Sorry, I replied to the wrong question. No, you would do `var result = connectie.retrie~~~`

Comment: @john 'var result = connectie.retrievecinemainfo(string, string, string)'. is only accessible in the forms, not in the class. you said that i need to assign the object that my method returns, this is outside of the method.